# Make Linux responding even when there is an I/O Error

Tags: linux, real-time

WHen there are harddisk's I/O error, my computer becomes unresponsive (mouse cannot be moved, screen freezes for a moment, keypress does nothing), for example when executing:

```
 sudo fsck.ext4 -fckyvt /dev/sdj1
```

or just normally copying/backuping files from faulty harddisk.

How to make my desktop responsive even there are I/O error? Change the kernel or something..

Current kernel: `Linux asd 4.4.32-rt43-2-rt-lts #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Sat Dec 17 15:50:06 WIB 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Here's a quick analogy:  How much time and money would you put in making your car drive normally with a flat tire, instead of replacing it?

Comment: It depends on both, your kernel configuration and your hardware. If the disk drive is really old and doesn't support DMA, or the equivalent, (or, however unlikely, DMA is disabled in the kernel) then the CPU needs to be heavily involved in disk I/O, hence the poor performance. But generally speaking, if you're getting I/O errors from a disk, just replace it.

Comment: @JuliePelletier yup, i'm currently badblock then backuping to another drive.. i have bought newer hdd

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it, AFAIK. This was an annoying issues whey I used diskettes (my first Linux distributions), CD-ROM, and it still happen now.

Try to avoid or reduce IO errors, e.g. using `ddrescue`, and plan much more time to copy a whole disk (vs with a healthy disk).

Comment: it's been 2 days to do bad sector check (badblock) not yet finished (70%)

Comment: @Kokizzu: I would not recommend badblock check, especially if it take so much time (so really damaged disk, you would not use it again). Stop it (you risk to lose more data with continously read bad sectors), and copy the disk content with `ddrescue` to the new disk. With tables created by ddrescue you can tell the system to check again and mark the already found badblock as bad.